# Convert a list into dataframe, and join into another dataframe

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I would like to convert a list with 44928 rows into a data frame, then merge into another dataframe with same number of rows (44928).

[image: List]

This list is inside a converted json response:

[image: Json]

Therefore, I would like to convert this list into a dataframe:

```
Data[["Axes"]][["Tuples"]][[1]]


      Ordinal                                                                      Members
1           0             2017, Orcamento, Faturamento, Total, Total das Áreas de Negócios
2           1                                2017, Orcamento, Faturamento, Total, Software
3           2                                   2017, Orcamento, Faturamento, Total, Hélio
4           3                                  2017, Orcamento, Faturamento, Total, Daniel
5           4                                    2017, Orcamento, Faturamento, Total, Soja
6           5                               2017, Orcamento, Faturamento, Total, São Paulo
7           6                                2017, Orcamento, Faturamento, Total, Campinas
8           7                                  2017, Orcamento, Faturamento, Total, Cuiabá
9           8                            2017, Orcamento, Faturamento, Total, Monte Alegre
 [44928 rows ]
```

Then I would like to join with this dataframe:

```
Data[["Cells"]][["Value"]]

Value
285174806
2
63776432
3
33220232
4
30556200
5
59531944
6
42022921
7
NA
8
NA
9
NA
10
NA
11
17509023
12
NA
13
NA
14
64537200
5
32850380
[44928 rows ]
```

A dataframe, separating each element list of "members" by column, then joining with "value" dataframe.

Comment: Provide a neat reproducible example and I can almost guarantee you will get good answers

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
c <- as.data.frame(Data[["Cells"]][["Value"]])
b <- as.data.frame(t(apply(Data[["Axes"]][["Tuples"]][[1]], 1, unlist)))
D <- cbind(b, c)
```